# Datatables Jquery plugin not supporting injection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using jQuery ajax call to return data as html to an empty tag `<table id=table01></table>` using

```
$('table #table01').html(data);
```

Table is rendered and filled with data properly, but when I want to sort columns using column header, I get an error message ***No data available in table***

Am I doing something wrong, or DataTables plugin for jQuery does not work with injected html.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$('table#table01').html(data);` (no space in the selector)?

Comment: Clive, that does not influence the problem, since the data is loaded propely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That I know of you don't inject html. It is certainly not the intended way of using the plugin as it essentially defeats the purpose. It is saying 'no data' because you literally gave the plugin no data to store in a cache somewhere and be able to sort, paginate, etc. All you did was append the html to the table tag ( not the datatable ). If you use the built in ajax functionality of datatables you just return the data you want in the table as json ( or another format if you supply the parsing ) and datatables automatically converts it to both the dom objects for display AND jquery objects for sorting and such.

This also makes your life alot easier.

P.S. when you do use the ajax functionality of the plugin its actually wrapping your table in a bunch of divs and adding a number of elements to it so the header you are clicking on isn't technically all that 'tied' to your table you declared in html if that makes sense? It is tied to a cache of objects that datatables uses to render the table for you.

here is an example of how to use ajax and dt 
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add data to the table after it has already been initialised you need to use the API: http://datatables.net/api#fnAddData . This allows DataTables to see what you are adding and process it accordingly. Directly injecting HTML won't work, because DataTables has no idea that this has happened - thus it tried to put in place what it does know on a redraw (no data in this case).

The alternative is to initialise the table after you set up the after you do the HTML injection (possibly destroying the table as olivieradam666 suggests).

Allan

Answer (score 1):

The most probable answer is that you are messing with the plugin internals. If your library provides a setter method for content just use it. If not, I think a safer approach would be to destroy your table, fill a new one with your data and then reinstanciate datatable widget on it.